# Where can I download a raster with the elevation data of the whole US?

Tags: geospatial

I know about USGS and USDA have DEM files but they are in small blocks, and I need the whole country. The closest that I've been with solving this is finding this [website](https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/elevation/folder/18297406380?sortColumn=date&sortDirection=desc&pageSize=20&pageNumber=0) that contains all the files that I need but I can't download cause there is a limit of 15gb to download. Moreover, I would like to have the whole country in one file.

Do you know where to find it? Preferably 30m resolution?

Comment: You would probably need at least 250 GB of free space to even download and unzip this data.

Comment: is the limit daily? annually? happy to help crowdsource this with you if it gets you to your goal.

Comment: @Kotebiya this is not a problem.

Comment: @albert thanks!! I think the limit is at the time. I was thinking in preparing a python script to webscrape everything. But I don't know how to get the list of files.

Comment: for....each of the 62 pages of results?

Comment: @Albert yes. I've been trying to find the static addresses for all these files with no luck.

Comment: what have you got so far? you can automate through each results page by altering vars in url. here's page 2: https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/elevation/folder/18297406380?sortColumn=date&sortDirection=desc&pageSize=20&pageNumber=1  thats to get the names. and the names correlate to urls of zips like this: https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/elevation/file/131536995180 you just have to swap out the ids. didn't dig far enough to see what actual download url is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [National Contours](ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elev/GDB/National_Contours.zip) file. You could also try using an FTP program such as filezilla to retrieve [these rasters](ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/Elevation/1/).

Comment: I think contour files doesn't work for me because I need to calculate slopes after getting elevation data. The FTP address seems super useful though! I'll give it a try and post if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ended up downloading all of them through filezilla. Thanks!